# AJAX Getting requesting server time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have an exam tomorrow on AJAX only recently started using ajax. I am tasked to create a html page that will request server time when a button is clicked. The functions have to be saved in a javascript file. Cant seem to get it this work but got others to work. Also i'm using WAMPServer.
Heres the html part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
    displaybox {width:150px; background-color:#FFF; border:2px solid #000; padding:10px; font:24px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    body{ background-color:#06F; text-align:center}
</style>
<title>Ajax Demo</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Ajax.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="getServerTime()">
<h1>AJAX Demo</h1>
<h2> Getting the server time without refreshing the page</h2>
<div id="showtime" class="displaybox"></div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Get Server Time" onclick="getServerTime()"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And the .js file called ajax.js:**

```
function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
var request;
var err;
   try {
          request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
   catch(err) {
       try {
             request = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp");
           }
       catch (err) {
                      try { 
                             request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
                          }
                      catch (err) {
                                     request = false;
                                  }
                   }
              }
   return request;  
}

function useHttpResponse(){
    if(http.readyState==4)
    {
        if(http.status==200)
        {
            var timeValue = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("timenow")[0];
            documnet.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = timeValue.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML ='<img src="Wait.gif">';
    }
}

function getServerTime(){
    var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();
    if (!http){
        document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Request errorr!";
        return;}
    var myurl ='telltimeXML.php';
    var myRand = parseInt(math.random()*99999999999);
    var modurl =myurl +"?rand="+myRand;
    http.open("GET",modurl,true);
    http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
    http.send(null);    
}
```

**telltimeXML.php**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    sleep(3);
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><clock1><timenow>" .date('H:i:s')."</timenow></clock1>";
?>
```

Comment: Typo: `documnet` should be `document`.

Comment: Didn't you get an error in the Javascript console because of that?

Comment: Learn to use your debugger!

Comment: Using dreamweaver to create it. Fixed the typo still no result

Comment: I assume you are using Internet Explorer, hit F12 and open the F12 tools while you are running it, take a look at what's going on in there

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
 `var http` was defined within a function, `math.random` should have been `Math.random` and `documnet.getElementById` should have been `document.getElementById`.
Updated Code:

```
var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();
function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
var request;
var err;
   try {
          request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
   catch(err) {
       try {
             request = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp");
           }
       catch (err) {
                      try { 
                             request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
                          }
                      catch (err) {
                                     request = false;
                                  }
                   }
              }
   return request;  
}

function useHttpResponse(){
    if(http.readyState==4)
    {
        if(http.status==200)
        {
            var timeValue = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("timenow")[0];
            document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = timeValue.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML ='<img src="images/Wait.gif">';
    }
}

function getServerTime(){

    if (!http){
        document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Request errorr!";
        return;}
    var myurl ='telltimeXML.php';
    var myRand = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999999);
    var modurl =myurl +"?rand="+myRand;
    http.open("GET",modurl,true);
    http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
    http.send(null);    
}



        http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
        http.send(null);    
    }
```

Thanks Everyone!